# Prove that $\frac{1}{k}D_{1}(x,y) \leq D_{2}(x,y) \leq k D_{1}(x,y)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ be distances in $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $D_{1}(x,y)= \sum_{r=1}^{k}|x_{r} - y_{r}|$ and $D_{2}(x,y)= \sqrt{\sum_{r=1}^{k}|x_{r} - y_{r}|^{2}}$. Prove that $\frac{1}{k}D_{1}(x,y) \leq D_{2}(x,y) \leq k D_{1}(x,y)$.

What I carry is the following

We know by definition that:

$D_{1}(x,y)= \sum_{r=1}^{k}|x_{r} - y_{r}|=|x_{1}-y_{1}|+...+|x_{k}-y_{k}|$

$D_{2}(x,y)= \sqrt{\sum_{r=1}^{k}|x_{r} - y_{r}|^{2}}= \sqrt{|x_{1}-y_{1}|^{2}+...+|x_{k}-y_{k}|^{2}}$

Then $D_{2} \leq D_{1}$ but I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Part
$$kD_{2}(x,y)\geq k*max{|x_{r}-y_{r}|}\geq \sum_{r=1}^{k} |x_{r}-y_{r}|$$
2nd Part
$$\frac{1}{k}D_{2}(x,y)\leq\frac{1}{k}*k*max{|x_{r}-y_{r}|}=max{|x_{r}-y_{r}|}\leq \sum_{r=1}^{k} |x_{r}-y_{r}|$$

Equality if $r=1$.